# Mechanical damper built in to vent fan?

Tags: air-conditioning, ventilation

Are there any bathroom fans or range hood fans that have a mechanical damper built in that fully seals when the fan is turned off? In other words, it shouldn't let any air in OR out when the fan is off.

I can hear the dampers that I currently have flap open in the wind. I've also seen thermal images of fans showing that a significant amount of thermal leakage is occuring. For instance, see the comments [here](http://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/community/forum/green-products-and-materials/21014/why-are-bath-fan-dampers-so-lousy).

The ["Larson Fan" damper](http://www.larsonfan.com/index.php?app=cms&ns=display&ref=Why) might be what I'm looking for, but I can't be 100% sure from the website's diagrams, and it'd be an expensive gamble.

This seems like it should be an easy thing to solve, and an expensive source of energy loss, so I'm surprised I've found so little information.

Comment: An alternative may be a ventilation fan with heat recovery. I have an EnviroVent HeatSava in my bathroom and it works extremely well - it runs constantly on a low setting, increasing speed if it detects high humidity.

Answer (score 1):

My high efficiency water heater has an electric damper.  Conventional butterfly plate.  The unit had a separate data sheet, so it wasn't part of the furnace itself.

Try HVAC stores.  Explain the problem.  You may be able to find an off the wall solution. Failing that, you may be able just run an electric damper in parallel with the fan.   There would be some back pressure while the fan started, and the damper was opening.  May shorten fan life a trifle.

I think Allied Granger carries electric dampers.

Another way that isn't as effective but may be sufficient is to spring load the vent slats on a conventional fan exit, or wire weights (washers work well) to the slats so they close better.  This would decrease the efficiency of the fan, as it would take more pressure to open the slats.